# UI not updating in main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

This is really driving me nuts.

I have a button, and if that button is touched it will call a method that updates the UI. Here's the method in question:

```
- (void)loadLevelWithImagePath:(NSString *)imagePath difficulty:(int)difficulty modelName:(NSString *)modelName
{
    // do stuffs
}
```

Except that it doesn't.

However when I enclose the whole method body in:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do stuffs
}
```

It works!

However, I am baffled because when I put a breakpoint in the method, according to the debugger it is already in the main thread. Also If I put these 2 checks:

```
- (void)loadLevelWithImagePath:(NSString *)imagePath difficulty:(int)difficulty modelName:(NSString *)modelName
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread]);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%d", [NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread]);
        // do stuffs
    }
}
```

Both returns TRUE!

So my question is, why is the UI not updating? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show us how you are updating the UI, attach the full code please.

Comment: I updated the UI in many ways: changing frames, adding views, setting the text of a label, etc. None of them works outside the dispatch_async, but when I put them inside dispatch_async they magically work. Example of such code: self.nameLabel.text = @"foo";

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the methods and see if `self.nameLabel` or any UI related object is nil.

Comment: It'd be good if we catch glimpse of some of your Update UI stuff.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard? If yes then check constraints over UIView/Controls.

Comment: @ValentinRadu wow thanks! They are surprisingly null! It turns out that I initialized my UI stuffs inside vieWDidLoad, and my UI-updating method got called before viewDidLoad. Thanks!

Comment: This is most likely because you're dispatch_async is pushing the tasks to the end of the main queue, so your viewDidLoad happens first. This is called a race condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a `nil` problem, however, you provide too little info to know for sure. The reason it works with `dispatch_async` and doesn't without is not necessarily the thread you're calling the methods from, it could be that, at the time when you call the code, some of your UI objects are nil. When you call `dispatch_async` you add the job to the queue but since all dispatch queues are first-in, first-out data structures, you actually add the job at the end of the run loop, which potentially gives time for initialisation (wherever that is done)

Comment: Well, actually, when a button (from another view controller) is pressed, it will alloc and init the view controller that contains the method in my question, calls the method in my question, and then finally calls another method show which would add the view controller's main view into the view hierarchy.